Vue 3 convert output of Quill editor Delta object to Html and display the Html
I am designing an app where users can comment using a rich text editor and those are displayed as a  html object.
This is the code to take comments:
<quill-editor theme="snow" v-model:content="newComment"></quill-editor>

Where:
const newComment = ref('')


Now assuming that I want to show the comment (while taking into account all the features of the input, such as bullet points or bold text), I have this element
<div v-html="newComment"></div>


But the output of this div is [object Object], not the one I expected. Alternately, if I write <div>{{newComment}}</div> I just get a Delta object like { "ops": [ { "insert": "aaa\n" } ] } .
I read the documentation and similar code. There is some existing code but I could not find Vue 3 composition API case.

It's working correctly. you can check here

@NileshMishra Thank you. Are you sure the codebox is visible? I tried with two accounts and it says something went wrong and I cannot see the code

Sorry, I forgot to make it public before. Now you should be able to access it.

@NileshMishra Thanks! I don't know for some reasons (I am using Vue3) the v-html sometimes does not show some html elements, for instance bullet points or ordered list. I ended up using another Quill editor for displaying html, but this time with readonly mode and theme=bubble so that it resembles a v-html div

You have to specify the content type.
<quill-editor theme="snow" v-model:content="newComment" content-type="html"></quill-editor>

It will works
